# List failing on second run

Tags: python, list

I am currently trying to program a mathematical card trick, which asks the user what pile their random card is in. However, the second time it runs (the 'trick phase' has to occur 3 times for the trick to work) the list index becomes out of range. I am unsure where exactly the problem lies and will attach the current version so you can try to run it to see clearer. Thanks!

```
import random

def makedeck():
  listy = []
  cardsindeck = 0
  while cardsindeck != 21:
    suit = random.randint(1,4)
    if suit == 1:
      suit = "D"
    elif suit == 2:
      suit = "H"
    elif suit == 3:
      suit = "S"
    else:
      suit = "C"
    cardtype = random.randint(1,13)
    if cardtype == 1:
      card = "A"
    elif cardtype == 2:
      card = "2"
    elif cardtype == 3:
      card = "3"
    elif cardtype == 4:
      card = "4"
    elif cardtype == 5:
      card = "5"
    elif cardtype == 6:
      card = "6"
    elif cardtype == 7:
      card = "7"
    elif cardtype == 8:
      card = "8"
    elif cardtype == 9:
      card = "9"
    elif cardtype == 10:
      card = "10"
    elif cardtype == 11:
      card = "J"
    elif cardtype == 12:
      card = "Q"
    else:
      card = "K"
    cardandsuit = (card + suit)
    if cardandsuit not in listy:
      listy.append(cardandsuit)
      cardsindeck = cardsindeck + 1
  return listy

def dealdeck(listy):
  list1 = []
  list2 = []
  list3 = []
  for i in range(len(listy)):
    if i % 3 == 0:
      list1.append(listy[i])
    elif i % 3 == 1:
      list2.append(listy[i])
    else:
      list3.append(listy[i])
  return[list1, list2, list3]

def makepiles(pile1,pile2,pile3):
  print("Pile 1\t\tPile 2\t\t Pile 3\t\t")
  for i in range(7):
    print(pile1[i],"\t\t",pile2[i],"\t\t",pile3[i],"\t\t")

def usercardpile():
  userinput = input("What pile is your card in?")
  if userinput == "1" or userinput.title() == "One":
    return 1
  elif userinput == "2" or userinput.title() == "Two":
    return 2
  elif userinput == "3" or userinput.title() == "Three":
    return 3
  else:
    print("Please only write 1, 2 or 3")
    return usercardpile()


listy = makedeck()
pile1, pile2, pile3 = dealdeck(listy)
for i in range(1,4):
  newlisty = makepiles(pile1,pile2,pile3)
  userspile = usercardpile()
  if userspile == 1:
    newlisty = (pile2,pile1,pile3)
  elif userspile == 2:
    newlisty = (pile1,pile2,pile3)
  else:
    newlisty = (pile1,pile3,pile2)
  pile1, pile2, pile3 = dealdeck(newlisty)

print("Your card is",newlisty[10])
```

Comment: Consider keeping a mapping of cardtype to card so you don't need to write  a wall of `if`s in your code.

Comment: I'm pretty new so I don't really understand. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is with this line of code:

```
newlisty = makepiles(pile1, pile2, pile3)
```

You're expecting `makepiles` to return 3 lists, whereas it returns `None` (no explicit item returned).

I imagine if you were to return the piles from that function, it'd work.

The other thing is, You are doing this:

```
newlisty = (pileX, pileY, pileZ)
```

This will create a tuple of lists, and you will iterate over the entire lists rather than the individual cards. I believe you want

```
newlisty = pile1 + pile3 + pile2`
```

This'll create a composite list of 21 elements by linearly combining the smaller piles.

---

Other comments:

Consider storing your decktype and card type in `dict`s. That way, you can quickly lookup and generate your piles without having to write a long set of `if` statements. Example:

You can reduce

```
cardtype = random.randint(1,13)
if cardtype == 1:
  card = "A"
elif cardtype == 2:
  card = "2"
elif cardtype == 3:
  card = "3"
elif cardtype == 4:
  card = "4"
elif cardtype == 5:
  card = "5"
elif cardtype == 6:
  card = "6"
elif cardtype == 7:
  card = "7"
elif cardtype == 8:
  card = "8"
elif cardtype == 9:
  card = "9"
elif cardtype == 10:
  card = "10"
elif cardtype == 11:
  card = "J"
elif cardtype == 12:
  card = "Q"
else:
  card = "K"
```

To...

```
cardtype_lookup = { 1 : 'A', 2 : '2', 3 : '3', .... 12 : 'K' } 

card = cardtype_lookup[random.randint(1, 13)]
```

...And so on.

Comment: Thanks so much man! Really helped me out on this one :D I'll be sure to use the advice about lookup in the future too :)

Comment: One more improvement: instead of choosing a random card, then checking if it is already in the deck you can just generate a deck containing all cards, then shuffle it using `random.shuffle`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Ooh, good idea. `from itertools import product; from random import shuffle; cards = [''.join(x) for x in list(product(list('DHSC'), list('A123456789JQK') + ['10']))]; shuffle(cards); cards[:21]`

Comment: I'm not sure you fully embraced what his overall script is trying to do. The issue is not that the makepiles function does not return anything, since its purpose is simply displaying the piles to the user before prompting them for an input. The actual problem was that he thought he needed to assign his function to a variable rather than simply calling it to generate the printed output. Same with the suggestion of using a dict for the card lookups. The real purpose is generating 21 unique cards, so it is better to generate the cards directly than simply offering a more efficient lookup.

Comment: @jack6e You're right, now that I look at it. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting a few issues with your code beyond just the final iterations. Below are some suggestions along with comments that I believe accomplishes your purpose.

```
from random import shuffle

# Function for generating 21 random cards
def makedeck():

    # Create 52 cards by suit and cardtype
    listy = [card + suit for card in ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'] for suit in ['D','H','S','C']]

    # Shuffle the list
    shuffle(listy)

    # Choose only the first 21 items of that list
    listy = listy[:21]

    return listy

# Function for dividing 21-card deck into 3 equally-sized piles
def dealdeck(listy):

    # Iterate over listy, stepping by 3, starting with the first, second, and third item
    list1 = listy[::3]
    list2 = listy[1::3]
    list3 = listy[2::3]

    # Return the three lists as three items to correspond to the three piles of the call
    return list1, list2, list3

# This works
def makepiles(pile1,pile2,pile3):
    print("Pile 1\t\tPile 2\t\t Pile 3\t\t")
    for i in range(7):
        print(pile1[i],"\t\t",pile2[i],"\t\t",pile3[i],"\t\t")

# This works
def usercardpile():
    userinput = input("What pile is your card in?")
    if userinput == "1" or userinput.title() == "One":
        return 1
    elif userinput == "2" or userinput.title() == "Two":
        return 2
    elif userinput == "3" or userinput.title() == "Three":
        return 3
    else:
        print("Please only write 1, 2 or 3")
        return usercardpile()

listy = makedeck()
pile1, pile2, pile3 = dealdeck(listy)
for i in range(1,4):
    # Because this function does not return anything, it should be run on its own, and not assigned to a variable
    makepiles(pile1,pile2,pile3)

    userspile = usercardpile()

    # Now you want to re-order the piles based on user input. Because these are lists, you can simply add them together in a new order to create a newly arranged list
    if userspile == 1:
        newlisty = pile2 + pile1 + pile3
    elif userspile == 2:
        newlisty = pile1 + pile2 + pile3
    else:
        newlisty = pile1 + pile3 + pile2

    # Now you create new piles based on the re-sorted list and re-iterate
    pile1, pile2, pile3 = dealdeck(newlisty)

# Uses .format method instead
print("Your card is {}".format(newlisty[10]))
```